# Samba group doesn't appear on Network Neighborhood

Tags: linux, windows, networking, samba

I have a samba server (Samba version 3.6.9-151.el6).
My ip server has multiple ip address, and it uses dns proxy for name resolution.

I have 2 problem:

1. Samba share works with IP but not with hostname from Windows Xp.
2. Samba group doesn't appear on Network Neighborhood

My dns works and I'm able to make name resolution on all my ip address.

Only pc on network 192.168.1.0/24 see samba shared folder, the pc on network
192.168.168.0 and 172.16.0.0 don't see shared folder.

Below is the smb.conf about my request related part:

```
workgroup = SERVER
server string = ServerXXX Samba Server Version %v
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.1. 192.168.168. 172.16.0.
deadtime = 0
keepalive = 300
lanman auth = yes
client lanman auth = yes
local master = yes
preferred master = no

wins support = yes
dns proxy = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like NetBIOS name resolution doesn't work at all. are the xp clients and the server on the same ip network?
remember that NetBIOS primarily uses broadcast to announce network names.
of you are both ends of the smb session on different ip networks then you need clients to register to the wins server

Comment: 1) yes both the server and xp clients are on the same ip network

Comment: Do you have any firewall enabled on either the client and the server? More specifically check that udp port 137 is opened

Comment: no, both are connected on same switch

Comment: You can have firewalling rules on the server itself on even (but less likely) on the client. Check on ubuntu firewall with iptables -nvL to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Network Neighborhood still relies on the old NetBEUI protocol and is non-routable.  You should be able to browse for computers that are in the same subnet.  NetBEUI is a broadcast protocol and produces lots of traffic.  If you talked to your network person, a bridge could be made and it would pass the NetBEUI traffic through but it's not something you really want to do.  It could really slow things down.

EDIT: Sorry, my bad - this explains issue #2, not showing up in Network Neighborhood.
Are you running a WINS server?  This may fix issue #1, IP works but names don't.  WINS, in a round-about way, works a bit like DNS - associates a name with an IP address, but for Windows computers.

Comment: sorry but DNS is really nothing like Wins.... luckily! presenting them as similar is ackward and misleading. The only common thing between both protocols is that they both resolves names. Involved mechanisms could hardly be more different. and yes a wins server is running as shown by : wins support = yes

Comment: @FSUScoot if both server and xp clients are on network 192.168.1.0 alla works, the problem arise when xp client is on different network. For clarification the server have the following ip address: 192.168.1.60, 192.168.168.2, 172.16.0.2, 192.168.5.1. If the xp client if on network 192.168.1.0 all works, if ip client as address i.e. 172.16.0.5 Network Neighborhood doesn't works.

Comment: Sorry this is such a late response - It's correct that Network Neighborhood won't work between the two different networks, and even subnets for that matter.  This isn't a WINS or setup issue, it's a networking issue.  Your network routers/switches aren't permitting the NETBEUI traffic from one subnet to another, and for good reason - it produces a LOT of traffic because it's a broadcast protocol.